# Data Mapping with function

Tags: sql-server, vba, reporting-services

Can someone help me with this function.The purpose of this function should be to take values from data base and to change the names like

Deposit,Withdrawal,Manual Balance Correction,Cash Correction,HighRoller Deposit Correction,HighRoller Withdrawal Correction,Player To Player Send , Player To Player Receive,Cash In Cash Out Deposit,Cash In Cash Out Withdrawal,Tip Deposit,Tip Withdrawal.Original table in data base is

```
Id Name                    IsCredit
1  Deposit                      0 
2. Withdrawal                   0 
3. Manual Balance Correction    0
4. Cash Correction              0
5. HighRoller Correction        0 or 1
6. Player To Player             0 or 1
7. Cash In Cash Out             0 or 1
15. Tip                         0 or 1

Function GetTransactionTypeName(ByVal key As Integer, ByVal isCredit As Boolean) As String

Dim keys As Integer() = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,15}

Dim names As String() = {"Deposit", "Withdrawal", "Manual Balance Correction", "Cash Correction", "High Roller {0} Correction", _
"Player To Player {0}", "Cash In Cash Out {0}", "Tip {0}"}

Dim indx As Integer

For indx = 0 To Ubound(keys)
If keys(indx) = key Then
Exit For
End If
Next

If indx &gt;= Ubound(names) Then
Return key
End If

If key=7 Or key=5 Or Key=6 or Key=15 Then

If  isCredit Then
If key=7 Or key=5 Or key=15
Return [String].Format(names(indx) ," Deposit")
End If
If key=6
Return [String].Format(names(indx) ," Recieve")
End If
Else
If key=7 Or key=5 or key=15
Return [String].Format(names(indx) ," Withdrawal")
End If
If key=6
Return [String].Format(names(indx) ," Send")
End If
End If
End If

Return names(indx)

End Function
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question: What exactly is the code supposed to do? And what does it currently do? Which part of the code do you think might be the problem? And please fix the formatting of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply use a `SELECT CASE` statement?

```
Function GetTransactionTypeName(ByVal key As Integer, ByVal isCredit As Boolean) As String

    Select Case key
        Case 1
            Return "Deposit"
        Case 2
            Return "Withdraval"
        ...
        Case 15
            If isCredit Then
                "Tip In"
            Else
                "Tip Out"
            End If
        Case Else
            Return "(Unknown)"
    End Select

End Function
```

It's much easier to read and maintain, and since you only have 8 distinct key-values, I would bet that the complete code will be even shorter than your original code.

Comment: but i have also IsCredit value, so i want to have some combination like (1,0) , (2,0) , (3,0) , (4,0), (5,0), (5,1), (6,0), (6,1) , (7,0) , (7,1) , (15,0) (15,1)

Comment: Then simply add an If-statement below the Case-statement. I have updated my answer with an example of this for case 15.